# Excel formula to Sum a row up to specific column number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to sum a row like

```
A          B         C         D         E   
2          4         3         5         5
```

I want the  formula to sum from A1 to some column number like It can be up to column 4 (D1) or up to column 5 (E1). I can retrieve column number but how to add up to that column number is what I am asking for.
Start of sum is fixed A1 but end is dynamic (not fixed)

Any solution will be highly appreciated

Comment: which programming language?

Comment: Excel formula for this is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we want to sum up **part** of the first row.

Place the first column number in **A2** and the last column number in **A3**.  Then:

```
=SUM(INDEX(1:1,A2):INDEX(1:1,A3))
```

[image]

In your posted example, you would put 1 in **A2**.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to sum up the entire row `=SUM(2:2)` (to sum the values in row 2) or if you have some other data at the beginning (or you want the sum to show up at the beginning) you can do something like `=SUM(B2:XFD2)`

I got that last column name here: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-last-column-name-in-an-Excel-file
and checked it was the same as newer versions here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#ID0EBABAAA=Newer_versions

Comment: I want Sum like =SUM(A1: "here I want to use column number like upto column 2/3/4..... ")

Comment: @kashann, why? Would there be more data later on in the row?

Comment: `XFD` *is* the name of the last possible column in Excel--hence the cell `XFD2`. The formula ignore empty cells, which is why @JvdV asked if there would be other data somewhere else in the row that you would not want to include in the sum...

Comment: Yes there will be more data in the row but I only want to add to some specific columns which is not fixed

Comment: hmm... well then we need the information about your specific situation. If it's not fixed, how do _you_ know where you want to end the sum? Are there blank cells after? Does it change according to the day? etc.

Comment: No i just have the column number where the formula should end automatically. Like if coulmn number is 4 then the folmula will add A1up to D1. If column number is 5 the formula will add A1 up to E1. Using column number i need sum